# Problems animating ng-repeat directive template with d3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to make a category list with Angular and D3. I've created a directive for this list and some of the child nodes in my template use ng-repeat because I'd like to have angular build my html instead of d3.

My problem is that when trying to reference the ng-repeated elements with d3, they haven't been created yet. If I use the link function there are no items in the list. If I use the compile function I'm able to see 1 list item, but there should be at least 2.

[Seen Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fractalspawn/LcbMf/)

Taken from fiddle:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('targetingCategories', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<div>'+
        '<ul class="catList">'+
          '<li ng-repeat="cat in data.categories">'+
            '{{cat.name}}'+
            '<ul class="subCatList">'+
              '<li ng-repeat="subcat in cat.categories">{{subcat.name}}</li>'+
            '</ul>'+
          '</li>'+
        '</ul>'+
      '</div>',
    replace: true,
    compile: function($tEl, $attrs){

      // attach d3 on the TEMPLATE element, and look for list items
      var vis = d3.select($tEl[0]);
      var catList = vis.select('.catList');
      var catListFirstItem = vis.select('.catlist>li');
      var catListItems = vis.selectAll('.catList>li');

      console.log(catList); // 1 item returned (the ul)
      console.log(catListFirstItem); // 1 item returned (the first li)
      console.log(catListItems); // 1 items returned ??

      return function($scope, $el, $attrs){
        // attach d3 to INSTANCE element and look for list items
        var vis = d3.select($el[0]);
        var catList = vis.select('.catList');
        var catListFirstItem = vis.select('.catlist>li');
        var catListItems = vis.selectAll('.catList>li');

        console.log(catList); // 1 item returned (the ul)
        console.log(catListFirstItem); // 1 item returned (the first li)
        console.log(catListItems); // 0 items returned ??
      };

    }
  };
});
```

The idea is to have angular build my markup, and d3 animate it. I like the control that d3 gives me versus using CSS animations.

When I used d3 to create my list items this was [working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/fractalspawn/4YCR8/). I'm tempted to do that again, but I think putting the LIs in the template is a better architecture.

I'm thinking that I need to call a compile, or wait for one or something. I'm almost at the limit of my Angular knowledge so any education here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding my own potential answer, but leaving unmarked incase anyone else has something better.

For now, it seems that one way to accomplish this is to replace the LIs in my main template with other nested directives, specifically "mainCategory" and "subCat". I am then able to attach d3 to the appropriate instance element for animation. By including an index attribute property, I can control the delay to make animations staggered. It feels a bit convoluted and "backbone-esque" (objects for the sake of objects), but it solves my problems. It also allows me to attach some ng-clicks which would have been next to cumbersome/impossible to do with d3 creating my LIs.

Yes, I'm aware that my attribute is called "data" and could be problematic, but I'm not worried about that now. Any corrections on my use of services/controllers/directives are appreciated though :)

[updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fractalspawn/u3png/)

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('targetingCategories', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<div>'+
        '<ul class="catList">'+
          '<main-category ng-repeat="cat in data.categories" index="$index">'+
            '{{cat.name}}'+
            '<ul class="subCatList">'+
              '<sub-cat ng-repeat="subcat in cat.categories" index="$index" data="subcat">{{subcat.name}}</sub-cat>'+
            '</ul>'+
          '</main-category>'+
        '</ul>'+
      '</div>',
    replace: true
  };
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('mainCategory', function(targetingService){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      index: "=",
      data: "="
    },
    template: '<li ng-transclude ng-click="selectCategory($event, data);"></li>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function($scope, $el, $attrs){
      d3.selectAll($el).transition()
        .duration(500)
        .delay(function(){ return $scope.index*200; })
        .ease('elastic')
        .style('width', '100%')
        .style('padding', '10px');

      $scope.selectCategory = function($event, cat){
        $event.stopPropagation();
        targetingService.selectCategory(cat);
      };
    }
  };
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('subCat', function(targetingService){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      index: '=',
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<li ng-transclude ng-click="selectSubCategory($event, data)"></li>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function($scope, $el, $attrs){
      d3.selectAll($el).transition()
        .duration(100)
        .delay(function(d,i){ return 500+($scope.index*200); })
        .ease('linear')
        .style('height', '30px')
        .style('padding', '8px');

      $scope.selectSubCategory = function($event, subCat){
        $event.stopPropagation();
        targetingService.selectSubCategory(subCat);
      };
    }
  };
});
```